# Morris chart to fetch data from a local JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, morris.js

I am trying to create a morris [donut chart](http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?javascript,live). 
I have modified it to get data from a local json file, but for some reason it doesnt load the chart.No error in the console also.

Here is the html file

```
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Morris.js Donut Chart Example</title>
</head>
<body onLoad="drawChart()">
<div id="donut-example"></div>
</body>

<script>
      function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json); // show the info in console
});
        Morris.Donut({
              element: 'donut-example',
              data: jsonData
            });
      }
</script>
</html>
```

And here is my data.json file

```
  [ {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},     {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},     {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 25},     {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20} ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you need to understand and do changes,

```
function drawChart() {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function (json) { // callback function which gets called when your request completes. 
        Morris.Donut({
            element: 'donut-example',
            data: json // use returned data to plot the graph
        });
    });
}
```

### [jquery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Thanks for ur help,I am totally new to UI design. But there is not data getting loaded to the div `donut-example` . It still shows a blank page.

Comment: can you prepare a fiddle?

Comment: @GovindKailas [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LqR4R/2/)..I assume your ajax call works successfully and returns a data as your posted in your question..

Comment: Yes, when I hard code the data it comes perfectly. But load from json data file result in a blank page

Comment: @GovindKailas that means you have some issue's with your ajax call.can you please make sure you ajax call is returning data?..use console log to print data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47562/discussion-between-pilot-and-govind-kailas)

Comment: have u try using $.parseJSON(your_json_data) and place this  xkey: 'value',
   ykeys: ['label'],
   labels: ['label'],
   smooth: false

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your data conversion on server side you maybe parse it to json array again;

For example;

```
function drawChart() {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetJsonData", "Home")',
           function (data) {
               Morris.Donut({
                   element: 'donut-example',
                   data: JSON.parse(data),
                   formatter: function (x) { return x + "%" }
               });
           }
        );
    }
```